# How to combine lines in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

So i am new to regular expressions and i am learning them using a simple text editor only. I have the following file

```
          84544484N
          32343545M
          32334546E
          34456434M
```

I am trying to combine each pair of lines into one tab delimited line 
The result should be :

```
        84544484N  32343545M
        32334546E  34456434M
```

I wrote the following :

```
            Search: (.*?)\n(.*?)
            Replace: \1\t\2
```

this did not work can someone please explain why and give me the correct solution. Thank you!!

Comment: What is the text editor?

Comment: Sublime @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(.*?)\n(.*?)` pattern will never work well because the `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern will always return an empty string (since `*?` is a lazy matching quantifier and if it can return zero characters (and it can) it will. Use greedy matching and adjust the pattern like:

```
(.+)\r?\n *(.*)
```

or - since SublimeText uses Boost regex - you can match any newline sequence with `\R`:

```
(.+)\R *(.*)
```

and replace with `\1\t\2`. Note I replaced `*?` with `+` in the first capturing group because you need to match non-empty lines.

Regex breakdown:

- `(.+)` - one or more characters other than a newline  (as many as possible) up to
- `\R` - a newline sequence (`\r\n`, `\r` or just `\n`)
- `*` - a literal space, zero or more occurrences
- `(.*)` - Group 2: zero  or more characters other than a newline (as many as possible)

[image]
                                                                     /
[image]

Comment: can you please explain what is \r and why did you use it here, THANKSS

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return, and in a regex pattern I applied a `?` quantifier to it meaning *match one or zero occurrence* of it. It is more efficient to use `\R` - it will match all types of linebreaks.

Comment: Works like a boss with Sublime Text 3, thank you @WiktorStribiżew!